# Magento 2 - Paypal Button

Tags: magento2, paypal, quickview

Do you know if it's possible to add a PayPal button on the popup that appears when we add a product from Quickview?

Quickview :

[image]

Popup :

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need to Express checkout button in pop-up?

Comment: Yes exactly Dhiren

Comment: I post answer, please check and if it help do not fotgot to accept and upvote.

Comment: Thanks, I replied to your answer. Can you help me?

Comment: If you have new question, please ask it seprately. So other can also help you into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the following code into your phtml file which you used to show pop-up.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
$paypalexpress = $baseurl.'paypal/express/start/button/1/';
```

Now for the button using below html.

```
<div id="button">
    <a href="<?php echo $paypalexpress; ?>">
    <img id="btnPayPal" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help to put your code in the right file? I use the Weltpixel Quickview module

Comment: can you provide me the new question link here, So i will look into that and give you reply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Dhiren

Do you know how to manage the popup in the Weltpixel Quickview module?

I found this file :

> app/code/WeltPixel/Quickview/view/frontend/web/js/weltpixel_quickview.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'magnificPopup'
], function ($, magnificPopup) {
"use strict";

return {
    displayContent: function(prodUrl) {
        if (!prodUrl.length) {
            return false;
        }

        var url = window.weltpixel_quickview.baseUrl + 'weltpixel_quickview/index/updatecart';
        var showMiniCart = parseInt(window.weltpixel_quickview.showMiniCart);

        window.weltpixel_quickview.showMiniCartFlag = false;

        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
              src: prodUrl
            },
            type: 'iframe',
            closeOnBgClick: false,
            preloader: true,
            tLoading: '',
            callbacks: {
                open: function() {
                  $('.mfp-preloader').css('display', 'block');
                },
                beforeClose: function() {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').trigger('contentLoading');
                    $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST"
                  });
                },
                close: function() {
                  $('.mfp-preloader').css('display', 'none');
                },
                afterClose: function() {
                    /* Show only if product was added to cart and enabled from admin */
                    if (window.weltpixel_quickview.showMiniCartFlag && showMiniCart) {
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('.action.showcart').trigger('click');
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
              }
        });
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have new question, please ask it seprately. So other can also help you into that.

Comment: Ok sorry for this

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it, so it will help other in community as well.